# How to copy internal directory audio files to external directory in Android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, storage, mediastore, android-11

I have a music app which lets user purchase music, and used to store it in own folder in external storage(works perfect till android 10).

From android 11, initially I used getFilesDir(internal storage) and the version has been live on play store, now user isn't able to see the physical file in file manager, I am aware about how scoped storage work, if my files would have been in external directory, user would be able to see it in ASD(app specific directory) but now in internal storage that also isn't accessible.

All downloaded files are visible to me in emulator at path: /data/user/0/com.packagename/files/FolderName/Music/
But I need it to be accessible by user so that he can access it.

Also, Is there anyone founded a way to transfer(move,copy) our files to Shared Directory(Downloads/Music), I am aware it needs MANAGE_PERMISSION which wasn't allowed by Google.
Really appreciate any help.

Comment: You can copy your files as always to public directories like Download, Documents and Music. No difference at all.

Comment: But for that we need manager_external_permission, I already that tried google rejected our app.
Can it be done with only read_permission, please guide how to do that @blackapps

Comment: Please reread my comment. You can read there that there is no difference at all. No extra permissions needed does that mean.

Comment: @blackapps I tried to copy music from assets to music folder after your comment, that's successful, without any permission.
 now my files are stored in internal storage i.e. /data/user/0/com.packagename/files/FolderName/Music/, But I am not able to read files from there, it gives enoent error, can you please help it's very urgent for me, thanks

Comment: /data/user/0/com.packagename/files/FolderName/Music is an apps private folder and has nothing to do with the public Music folder. Files will not be visible by users using a file manager. So instead of asking help for a new problem you should first use a path that is visible by the user. As that was what you also asked.

Comment: I got your point, but some important audio files are already stored in internal storage(/data/user/0/com.packagename/files/FolderName/Music), which needs to be copy to shared directory(I know I am repeating what I already mentioned), so I am trying to find any way to read audio files from internal storage.

Comment: `which needs to be copy to shared directory` AND `so I am trying to find any way to read audio files from internal storage.` Well i cannot follow you. What have they to do with each other?

Comment: So, /storage/emulated/0/Music/FolderName/(MusicFile) needs to be accessible to user as he paid for the music file, but the music right now is at /data/user/0/com.packagename/files/FolderName/Music which he can't see even, let alone play it. So I want to read music file from data/user/0.... and write to /storage/emulated/0...(whole path), so he can see the file, play it, also it wont be deleted if app is uninstalled  @blackapps

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0...(whole path)` ?? Why not write the whole path? The path i ment in my first comment should that be.  Yes. I already long know what you want. But what is the problem doing so? You are not to the point with your problem description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think now you have option to backup your data, most probably your users are going to sue you.

No magical solution for this. I think @blackapps is just bluffing.